# Raspberry Pi quadcopter thrashes at high speeds

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, robotics, control-theory, pid-controller

I am attempting to build a raspberry pi based quadcopter. So far I have succeeded in interfacing with all the hardware, and I have written a PID controller that is fairly stable at low throttle. The problem is that at higher throttle the quadcopter starts thrashing and jerking. I have not even been able to get it off the ground yet, all my testing has been done on a test bench. Is this a problem with my code, or perhaps a bad motor? any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

here is my code so far:

QuadServer.java:

```
package com.zachary.quadserver;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import se.hirt.pi.adafruit.pwm.PWMDevice;
import se.hirt.pi.adafruit.pwm.PWMDevice.PWMChannel;

public class QuadServer {
    private static Sensor sensor = new Sensor();

    private final static int FREQUENCY = 490;

    private static double PX = 0;
    private static double PY = 0;

    private static double IX = 0;
    private static double IY = 0;

    private static double DX = 0;
    private static double DY = 0;

    private static double kP = 1.3;
    private static double kI = 2;
    private static double kD = 0;

    private static long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private static double last_errorX = 0;
    private static double last_errorY = 0;

    private static double outputX;
    private static double outputY;

    private static int val[] = new int[4];

    private static int throttle;

    static double setpointX = 0;
    static double setpointY = 0;

    static long receivedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NullPointerException {

        PWMDevice device = new PWMDevice();
        device.setPWMFreqency(FREQUENCY);

        PWMChannel BR = device.getChannel(12);
        PWMChannel TR = device.getChannel(13);
        PWMChannel TL = device.getChannel(14);
        PWMChannel BL = device.getChannel(15);

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(8080);


        Thread read = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    while(true) {
                    try {
                            byte receiveData[] = new byte[1024];
                            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                            String message = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                            throttle = (int)(Integer.parseInt((message.split("\\s+")[4]))*12.96)+733;
                            setpointX = Integer.parseInt((message.split("\\s+")[3]))-50;
                            setpointY = Integer.parseInt((message.split("\\s+")[3]))-50;

                        receivedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        };
        read.start();

        while(true)
        {
            Arrays.fill(val, calculatePulseWidth((double)throttle/1000, FREQUENCY));

            double errorX = -sensor.readGyro(0)-setpointX;
            double errorY = sensor.readGyro(1)-setpointY;

            double dt = (double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000;

            double accelX = sensor.readAccel(0);
            double accelY = sensor.readAccel(1);
            double accelZ = sensor.readAccel(2);

            double hypotX = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(accelX, 2)+Math.pow(accelZ, 2));
            double hypotY = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(accelY, 2)+Math.pow(accelZ, 2));


            double accelAngleX = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(accelY/hypotY));
            double accelAngleY = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(accelX/hypotX));

            if(dt > 0.01)
            {

                PX = errorX;
                PY = errorY;

                IX += errorX*dt;
                IY += errorY*dt;

                IX = 0.95*IX+0.05*accelAngleX;
                IY = 0.95*IY+0.05*accelAngleY;

                DX = (errorX - last_errorX)/dt;
                DY = (errorY - last_errorY)/dt;

                outputX = kP*PX+kI*IX+kD*DX;
                outputY = kP*PY+kI*IY+kD*DY;
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            System.out.println(setpointX);

            add(-outputX+outputY, 0);
            add(-outputX-outputY, 1);
            add(outputX-outputY, 2);
            add(outputX+outputY, 3);

            //System.out.println(val[0]+", "+val[1]+", "+val[2]+", "+val[3]);
            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-receivedTime < 1000)
            {
                BR.setPWM(0, val[0]);
                TR.setPWM(0, val[1]);
                TL.setPWM(0, val[2]);
                BL.setPWM(0, val[3]);
            } else 
            {
                BR.setPWM(0, 1471);
                TR.setPWM(0, 1471);
                TL.setPWM(0, 1471);
                BL.setPWM(0, 1471);
            }

        }
    }

    private static void add(double value, int i)
    {
        value = calculatePulseWidth(value/1000, FREQUENCY);
        if(val[i]+value > 1471 && val[i]+value < 4071)
        {
            val[i] += value;
        }else if(val[i]+value < 1471)
        {
            //System.out.println("low");
            val[i] = 1471;
        }else if(val[i]+value > 4071)
        {
            //System.out.println("low");
            val[i] = 4071;
        }
    }

    private static int calculatePulseWidth(double millis, int frequency) {
        return (int) (Math.round(4096 * millis * frequency/1000));
    }
}
```

Sensor.java:

```
package com.zachary.quadserver;

import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.*;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Sensor {
    static I2CDevice sensor;
    static I2CBus bus;
    static byte[] accelData, gyroData;
    static long accelCalib[] = new long[3];
    static long gyroCalib[] = new long[3];

    static double gyroX = 0;
    static double gyroY = 0;
    static double gyroZ = 0;

    static double accelX;
    static double accelY;
    static double accelZ;

    static double angleX;
    static double angleY;
    static double angleZ;

    public Sensor() {
        //System.out.println("Hello, Raspberry Pi!");
        try {
            bus = I2CFactory.getInstance(I2CBus.BUS_1);

            sensor = bus.getDevice(0x68);

            sensor.write(0x6B, (byte) 0x0);
            sensor.write(0x6C, (byte) 0x0);
            System.out.println("Calibrating...");

            calibrate();

            Thread sensors = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            readSensors();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    }
            };
            sensors.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void readSensors() throws IOException {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long sendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (true) {
            accelData = new byte[6];
            gyroData = new byte[6];
            int r = sensor.read(0x3B, accelData, 0, 6);
            accelX = (((accelData[0] << 8)+accelData[1]-accelCalib[0])/16384.0)*9.8;
            accelY = (((accelData[2] << 8)+accelData[3]-accelCalib[1])/16384.0)*9.8;
            accelZ = ((((accelData[4] << 8)+accelData[5]-accelCalib[2])/16384.0)*9.8)+9.8;
            accelZ = 9.8-Math.abs(accelZ-9.8);

            double hypotX = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(accelX, 2)+Math.pow(accelZ, 2));
            double hypotY = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(accelY, 2)+Math.pow(accelZ, 2));


            double accelAngleX = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(accelY/hypotY));
            double accelAngleY = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(accelX/hypotX));

            //System.out.println((int)gyroX+", "+(int)gyroY);

            //System.out.println("accelX: " + accelX+" accelY: " + accelY+" accelZ: " + accelZ);

            r = sensor.read(0x43, gyroData, 0, 6);
            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-time >= 5)
            {
                gyroX = (((gyroData[0] << 8)+gyroData[1]-gyroCalib[0])/131.0);
                gyroY = (((gyroData[2] << 8)+gyroData[3]-gyroCalib[1])/131.0);
                gyroZ = (((gyroData[4] << 8)+gyroData[5]-gyroCalib[2])/131.0);

                angleX += gyroX*(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000;
                angleY += gyroY*(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000;
                angleZ += gyroZ;

                angleX = 0.95*angleX + 0.05*accelAngleX;
                angleY = 0.95*angleY + 0.05*accelAngleY;

                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            //System.out.println((int)angleX+", "+(int)angleY);
            //System.out.println((int)accelAngleX+", "+(int)accelAngleY);
        }
    }

    public static void calibrate() throws IOException {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        {
            accelData = new byte[6];
            gyroData = new byte[6];
            int r = sensor.read(0x3B, accelData, 0, 6);
            accelCalib[0] += (accelData[0] << 8)+accelData[1];
            accelCalib[1] += (accelData[2] << 8)+accelData[3];
            accelCalib[2] += (accelData[4] << 8)+accelData[5];

            r = sensor.read(0x43, gyroData, 0, 6);
            gyroCalib[0] += (gyroData[0] << 8)+gyroData[1];
            gyroCalib[1] += (gyroData[2] << 8)+gyroData[3];
            gyroCalib[2] += (gyroData[4] << 8)+gyroData[5];
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        gyroCalib[0] /= i;
        gyroCalib[1] /= i;
        gyroCalib[2] /= i;

        accelCalib[0] /= i;
        accelCalib[1] /= i;
        accelCalib[2] /= i;
        System.out.println(gyroCalib[0]+", "+gyroCalib[1]+", "+gyroCalib[2]);
    }

    public double readAngle(int axis)
    {
        switch (axis)
        {
            case 0:
                return angleX;
            case 1:
                return angleY;
            case 2:
                return angleZ;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public double readGyro(int axis)
    {
        switch (axis)
        {
            case 0:
                return gyroX;
            case 1:
                return gyroY;
            case 2:
                return gyroZ;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public double readAccel(int axis)
    {
        switch (axis)
        {
            case 0:
                return accelX;
            case 1:
                return accelY;
            case 2:
                return accelZ;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Impossible to tell whether the problem is with the code or the motor unless you post the code and/or the motor.

Comment: I think you'll have more chances of getting help from the raspberry pi forums http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/ as this site is focused on programming questions.

Comment: There is no way to know given the information provided. [Tuning PID controllers](https://www.google.com/search?q=pid+tuning) is an art, your problem could be there. Incorrect controller implementation could also be an issue. Bad sensors, motor problems, or any number of other things subtle or not-so-subtle could also be the cause. You need to perform some more tests, gather and analyze data, and narrow down your problem. If you can narrow it down to a specific coding issue you can then ask here on SO. Otherwise you might try http://robotics.stackexchange.com or the Pi forums.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to setup different values for the gains of your controller based on different operating conditions. Then you should only be able to identify each condition of operation, change the gain of your PID accordingly, and validate the design. In your case, you could try to schedule the gain of the PID with throttle or other associated variable read from the available sensors.

Search for Gain Scheduling implementations:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/gain-scheduled-control-systems.html

This is a very useful technique which applies linear control design to non-linear systems with very satisfactory results.